# How to draw the outline of circle within it, in Android

Tags: drawing, android-canvas

I am trying to draw outlining of circle using this code.

```
private ShapeDrawable getDrawableEmptyCircle(int color){
    ShapeDrawable myDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());
    myDrawable.getPaint().setColor(color);
    myDrawable.setIntrinsicHeight( 50 );
    myDrawable.setIntrinsicWidth( 50);
    myDrawable.getPaint().setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    myDrawable.getPaint().setStrokeWidth(3);
//  myDrawable.setBounds(x, y, x + width, y + height);
    return myDrawable;
}
```

This function returns the drawable circle, outlined but outside the size of the circle. Which causes some distortion in my circle. This is how it looks like

[circle image http://picthost.net/image.php?di=YV8B](http://picthost.net/image.php?di=YV8B)

As you can see, its outline is not properly visible. can you help me?

**EDIT** : I am adding this drawable to background of the view.

1. I tried to increase the size of the view also, then the size of circle increases (but same problem).
2. I have tried adding margin to the view.
3. I also tried to enclose the view with a layout and adding some padding to it.

Comment: Is the view you are drawing in exactly 50 px wide and tall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long search and hit and trial, I found solution to this problem, Hope it will help others-

This problem got solved, when I defined my circle in the xml file instead of creating it by code.

Add this file, say empty_circle.xml and write this-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:shape="oval">
<corners android:radius="40dip"/>
<stroke android:color="@color/solid_green_color" android:width="2dip"/>
<solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
</shape>
```

And call this file from your function like:

```
Drawable myDrawable= (Drawable) context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.empty_circle);
myDrawable.setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```